# React-Calendar-TimeLine is it possible to change the color of text on the header?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-functional-component

[Text to be changed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iAiZT.jpg)

I tried multiple things to change the color of this text without success, I tried using styled components, a className, a direct stylesheet, a style prop on the component, I tried using CustonHeader component that the lib offers but I couldn't wrap my thoughts on how to change the color of this text, anybody can help me on how to do it?

Comment: We'd really need some code or a fiddle to help with this.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @matty sorry about that, but I already solved the problem as I posted the solution bellow, the thing is, I was having issues changing the collor of the component that I posted the picture on my question there isn't realy a code that I could provide because I was just asking if there was a prop of this component to change that text color or if it was even possible... english isn't my main language so forgive if its a bit hard to understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Solve this problem you can create a css file and call this class:

```
.react-calendar-timeline .rct-dateHeader-primary{
   color: black;
}
```

Comment: is it possible to change width also specialy cell size hieght and min width

Comment: Yes it is, but it's been a long time since I worked with this library, and I don't remember how I did it